# Issue with rails form select displaying results as hex

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, model, ruby-on-rails-5.1

I am trying to select a distinct column from a model then display those results in a select drop down. Everything seems to be working except the value of the column doesn't display. It displays some sort of hex value or something. Here is my variable:

```
@incidenttypes = Incident.select(:incidenttype).distinct.order("incidenttype")
```

This is the form select:

```
<%= f.select :incidenttype, @incidenttypes, {include_blank: true}, class: 'form-control' %>
```

The output looks like this: `#<Incident:0x0000000e97a88>`

Any thoughts on what I am doing wrong?

UPDATE: Here is the schema for the table:

```
create_table "incidents", force: :cascade do |t|
t.string "street"
t.string "city"
t.string "zip"
t.integer "dayofweek"
t.date "timeofday"
t.string "state"
t.string "incidenttype"
t.string "drnum"
t.string "weatherevent"
t.string "specialevent"
t.float "latitude"
t.float "longitude"
t.text "comments"
t.datetime "created_at", null: false
t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
end
```

This is the search form:

```
   <%= form_for(:search, url: incidents_path, method: :get) do |f| %>
    <div class="ui-bordered px-4 pt-4 mb-4">
      <div class="form-row">
        <div class="col-md mb-4">
          <label class="form-label">Type</label>
          <%= f.select :dayofweek, Incident.dayofweeks.keys, {:include_blank=> 'Any days', :selected => @dayofweek}, class: 'custom-select' %>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md mb-4">
          <label class="form-label">Incident Type</label>

          <%= f.select :incidenttype, options_for_select(@incidenttypes), {include_blank: true}, class: 'form-control' %>

        </div>
        <div class="col-md mb-4">
          <label class="form-label">Created date</label>
          <%= f.text_field :created_at, class: 'form-control', id: 'tickets-list-created', :autocomplete => :off, value: created_at_from_parameters %>

        </div>
        <div class="col-md col-xl-2 mb-4">
          <label class="form-label d-none d-md-block">&nbsp;</label>
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-secondary btn-block">Show</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <% end %>
```

Incident controller:

```
    class IncidentsController < ApplicationController
      before_action :set_incident, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

      # GET /incidents
      # GET /incidents.json
      def index
        if params[:search] && params[:search][:created_at].present?
          start_date, end_date = params[:search][:created_at].split(' - ')
        @incidents = Incident.where(created_at: start_date..end_date).where(dayofweek: params[:search][:dayofweek]).where(incidenttype: params[:search][:incidenttype])
        @dayofweek = params[:search][:dayofweek]
        @incidenttypes = Incident.order("incidenttype").pluck(:incidenttype, :incidenttype).uniq

        else
        @incidents = Incident.all
        end
      end

      def map
        @incidents = Incident.all
      end

      # GET /incidents/1
      # GET /incidents/1.json
      def show
      end

      # GET /incidents/new
      def new
        @incident = Incident.new
      end

      # GET /incidents/1/edit
      def edit
      end

      # POST /incidents
      # POST /incidents.json
      def create
        @incident = Incident.new(incident_params)

        respond_to do |format|
          if @incident.save
            format.html { redirect_to @incident, notice: 'Incident was successfully created.' }
            format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @incident }
          else
            format.html { render :new }
            format.json { render json: @incident.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
          end
        end
      end

      # PATCH/PUT /incidents/1
      # PATCH/PUT /incidents/1.json
      def update
        respond_to do |format|
          if @incident.update(incident_params)
            format.html { redirect_to @incident, notice: 'Incident was successfully updated.' }
            format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @incident }
          else
            format.html { render :edit }
            format.json { render json: @incident.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
          end
        end
      end

      # DELETE /incidents/1
      # DELETE /incidents/1.json
      def destroy
        @incident.destroy
        respond_to do |format|
          format.html { redirect_to incidents_url, notice: 'Incident was successfully destroyed.' }
          format.json { head :no_content }
        end
      end

      private
        # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
        def set_incident
          @incident = Incident.find(params[:id])
        end

        # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
        def incident_params
          params.require(:incident).permit(:street, :city, :zip, :dayofweek, :timeofday, :state, :incidenttype, :drnum, :weatherevent, :specialevent, :latitude, :longitude, :comments)
        end
    end
```

Comment: Could you share schema of Incident model?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To learn more [options_for_select](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-options_for_select) and [Select helper](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormBuilder/select)

Refactor your query as

```
@incidenttypes = Incident.order("incidenttype").distinct.pluck(:incidenttype, :id)
```

Use `options_for_select(@incidenttypes)`

```
<%= f.select :incidenttype, options_for_select(@incidenttypes), {include_blank: true}, class: 'form-control' %>
```

To use is with form follow as

```
@incidenttypes = Incident.order("incidenttype").distinct.pluck(:incidenttype, :incidenttype)
```

in optoptions_for_select(array of arrays of options and values, slected_value after submitting form)

```
<%= f.select :incidenttype, options_for_select(@incidenttypes, params[:incident][:incidenttype]), {include_blank: true}, class: 'form-control' %>
```

Comment: Thank you. That works. I was getting duplicates though so I removed the :id from the pluck.

Comment: One more issue. How do I retain the selected value in the select field after submit? Trying , :selected => @incidenttypes does not seem to work.

Comment: However `<%= f.select : incidenttype ...%>` automatically  sets as selected after submitting form, still you can pass is explicitly as `options_for_select(@incidenttypes, selected_value)` here `selected_value` will be attributed of incidenttype (object of Incidenttype) more likely is should be `options_for_select(@incidenttypes, Incidenttype.id)`

Comment: `options_for_select(@incidenttypes, incident.incidenttype)`

Comment: None of those suggestions seem to be working. I am not selecting the id as that was giving me duplicates. I am only selecting the incidenttype field.

Comment: You should not remove :id as `options_for_select([['x', 1], ['y', 2], ['z', 3]...)` will accept such type argument which mean ['x', 1] => x will be an option and 1 => will be corresponding value to be save after submit for.

Comment: That makes sense but when I open the dropdown there are multiple values for the same incident types depending on how many records have them.

Comment: Can you show the columns in Incident model , so that i can figure out, but as i suggested, for now you should use as i given in answer and use `options_for_select(@incidenttypes)` it will automatic set selected value which is saved in db after submitting form .https://apidock.com/rails/v3.2.8/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/options_for_select

Comment: @spacerobot `@incidenttypes = Incident.order("incidenttype").distinct.pluck(:incidenttype, :id)` can you use this to get distinct values, it may be `uniq` were not working as expected.

Comment: I have updated my original post with the schema for the table.

Comment: @spacerobot that's fine as I gueesed and answer should work as expected.  You will have options incidenttype and value to be saved as id  which has been fetched by pluck query.

Comment: When I add the ID though it is displaying multiples and when I hit the search button it is passing an ID numerical value through and not the incidenttype in string format. The form is a search form where I can select date, incidenttype and dayofweek to retrieve results.

Comment: @spacerobot alright so you are using this select box as search form , and you don't want to pass id as value with form am i right?

Comment: Yes that is correct. I'll update my post with the whole form and controller.

Comment: I have updated the original post to include the full controller.

Comment: Got it working finally. Had to add the selected param inside the options_for_select parentheses. Final input: 

`<%= f.select :incidenttype, options_for_select(@incidenttypes, :selected => params[:search][:incidenttype]), {include_blank: true}, class: 'form-control' %>`